# Scrape the angellist startup data

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I want to scrape data from `https://angel.co/companies?locations[]=1688-United+States`. Can anyone please guide me what should I do?

I know I should use BeautifulSoup or Selenium but eventually I found out that this web page is not static it changes its data time by time can anyone please guide me through it?

I think the angellist API web page is not working anymore.

Comment: Can you add what you want to extract, the data format.

Comment: @vish use `Selenium`

Comment: hello @tek nath if you open https://angel.co/companies?locations[]=1688-United+States   this URL you will see one table, i want to extract table with column   (Company , Location, Market, Website, Employees, Total Raised ) these 6 column i want to extract

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait few second till table on page is generated:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time

chrome_driver = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + '/chromedriver'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)
browser.get("https://angel.co/companies?locations[]=1688-United+States")
time.sleep(3)

data_row = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('base.startup')

for item in data_row:
    print('-'*100)
    company = item.find_element_by_class_name('name').text
    location = item.find_element_by_class_name('column.location').text
    print(company)
    print(location)
```

Output:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WP Engine
Austin
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Kissmetrics
San Francisco
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bluesmart
San Francisco
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Star.me
Los Angeles
...
...
```

Comment: @vish read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python

Comment: hello when i use this path "\Users\Dell User\Downloads\Compressed\chromedriver_win32"   it shows an earror: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape      please help

Comment: @Zarakai Kenpachi can you please make a correct path of   C:\Users\Dell User\Downloads\Compressed\chromedriver_win32    how should i write it ? i have tried  chrome_driver = "C:\\Users\\Dell User\\Downloads\\Compressed\\chromedriver_win32"
still not working shows path does not found

Comment: @vish sorry con't test that. I'm Linux user